# Sqlite throws null exception on one db read but not another

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have two SELECT statements in a VB.NET sqlite code block.

The first block returns a value, the second returns a null reference, object exception. Both tables have identical date columns. They are from two different tables in the same DB. the paramaters reference a from and to "Datetime picker". The db is set as DATE. here are the blocks.

Any help?

```vb
Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connstring)
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) from clientinfo where ID  > 0 "
        If cmd.ExecuteScalar = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ' add selected leads
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(LeadID) ld From Leaddata where  Capptdate between @dtfrom22 and  @dtto22 "
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtfrom22", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtstatsfrom.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtto22", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStatsTo.Value
            Dim RDR As SQLiteDataReader
            RDR = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Using RDR
                txtstatstotalleads.Text = 0
                While RDR.Read()
                    txtstatstotalleads.Text = RDR.Item("ld").ToString()
                End While
            End Using
            'add selected Sales
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(SalesID) sd From Salesdata  where  saledate between   @dtStatsFrom23 and   @dtStatsTo23 "
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsfrom23", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtstatsfrom.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsto23", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStatsTo.Value
            RDR = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Using RDR
                txtStatsSales.Text = 0
                While RDR.Read()
                    txtStatsSales.Text = RDR.Item("sd").ToString()
                End While
            End Using
            'Add avg COMMISION TO stats FORM
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Avg(CommissionAmt) cm From SalesData where saledate between @dtfrom24 and @dtto24"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtfrom24", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtstatsfrom.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtto24", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStatsTo.Value
            RDR = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Using RDR
                txtStatsCommAvg.Text = 0
                While RDR.Read()
                    txtStatsCommAvg.Text = RDR.Item("cm").ToString()
                End While
            End Using
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: You aren't setting RDR in the second query.

Comment: I recommend that you avoid AddWithValue - it is possible for it to interpret things differently from what you wanted: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I had Parameters.add(@dtfrom23,sqltype.date)= dtStatsfrom.Value  didn't make any difference so i thought i'd try this.

Comment: Setting RDR ? it is declared at the beginning.  Don't need to declare it again.

Comment: Huh? The data reader you created there was for the first query. You need to create a new reader instance for the second query. Although you can re-use the `RDR` variable, you must set it again with a fresh reader.

Comment: @TOmalak If i delcare it as Dim RDR as SqliteDatareader = cmd.ExecuteReader, can't i then use Using RDR in all following code blocks under that cmd.connection

Comment: No, because you don't declare it as `Dim RDR as SqliteDatareader`, but as `Dim RDR as SqliteDatareader = cmd.ExecuteReader` (where `cmd` is the first SQLCommand) if you see the difference. This reader won't magically know that there is a second command somewhere later in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing here is *you never execute the second query*. **You need to call `cmd.ExecuteReader()` again.**

But there's more, too. This `With` here is wrong:

```
With RDR.Read
    txtStatsSales.Text = RDR.Item("sd").ToString()
End With
```

That doesn't actually check the result of the `Read()` function (and it is more idiomatic now in modern VB to always use parentheses with function calls). You probably wanted this:

```
If RDR.Read() Then
    txtStatsSales.Text = RDR.Item("sd").ToString()
End If
```

Additionally, it's more common to use a `While` loop here, *even when you only expect  one (or no) record*, and it's not necessary or helpful to check `HasRows` in this situation. Also, `AddWithValue()` can cause performance issues if not used carefully (probably okay in this specific  case, but it's good to be in the habit of using this other pattern) :

```vb
'add selected Sales
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(SalesID) sd FROM Salesdata WHERE saledate BETWEEN @dtStatsFrom23 AND @dtStatsTo23"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsfrom23", SqlType.Date).Value = dtstatsfrom.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsto23", SqlType.Date).Value = dtStatsTo.Value

Using RDR = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    txtStatsSales.Text = 0
    While RDR.Read() 
        txtStatsSales.Text = RDR("sd").ToString()
    End While
End Using
```

---

Based on the update to the question, I suggest an **initial** revision as below. This won't fix everything, but will give us a better foundation to work from. Also, to *really* suggest a full fix, I need to see a sample of the date values as they are stored in the tables.

```vb
Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connstring), _
      cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM clientinfo WHERE ID > 0", con)

    con.Open()
    If CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    cmd.CommandText  = "SELECT Count(LeadID) ld FROM Leaddata WHERE Capptdate between @dtFrom and @dtTo;" & vbCrLf
    cmd.CommandText &= "SELECT Count(SalesID) sd, Avg(CommissionAmt) cm FROM Salesdata WHERE saledate between @dtFrom and @dtTo;"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtFrom", SqliteType.Text).Value = dtstatsfrom.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtTo", SqliteType.Text).Value = dtStatsTo.Value
    Using RDR As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' add selected leads
        txtstatstotalleads.Text = "0"
        While RDR.Read()
            txtstatstotalleads.Text = RDR("ld").ToString()
        End While

        RDR.NextResult()

       'add selected Sales and avg commission
        txtStatsSales.Text = "0"
        txtStatsCommAvg.Text = "0"
        While RDR.Read()
            txtStatsSales.Text = RDR("sd").ToString()
            txtStatsCommAvg.Text = RDR("cm").ToString()
        End While

    End Using
End Using
```

Note how I was able to reduce indentation, which makes the code easier to follow, and also reduce round-trips to the database down to one by putting two queries in the same statement and two fields into one query.

But I still need to see sample data from the table to know how those dates are really formatted. `dtStatsFrom.Value` and `dtStatsTo.Value` are `DateTime` values, and right now you're getting the default `ToString()` result. We need to explicitly call `.ToString()` for those values, using an overload that specifies the exact format string we need to match the data in the table... and we need to hope the data is formatted in such a way as to make this practical. If you have the month-first format common the US, the `BETWEEN` expressions are still treating these as **string** rather than **dates**, and you won't see the results you expect.

Comment: No, that was typo. The real issue here is I forgot he was using Sqlite, which doesn't have a DateTime type. I should probably have used a string (as well calling ToString() with an explicit format string for the To/From values), but I can't just fix that without knowing for sure which method the OP is actually using to store those values

Comment: Neverfind, I see sqltype.date in the comments.

Comment: Joel Coehoom,   I changed the second block to everything you suggested except usingRDR=cmd.executeReader since intellisense tells me i already have it set above.  The first block returns values the second doesn't although i do get a "0" in the textbox.  This has to do with the datepicker format of short date.  SQlite doesn't like 1/1/2018. it has 2018-1-1 in the date field.  regardless of that, why does the first block work and not the second. i have tried all versions of cdate, strftime etc.

Comment: i have set formats to strings, added format("yyyy-mm-dd" ) and a variety of changes.  still the first one works as is but not the second even with a while loop. FYI  this works fine in SQLite Studio with specific dates.

Comment: @B.Feld Intellisense is lying to you. The variable is _declared_, and has a reader object, but that object is already closed. **`ExecuteReader()` is what actually runs your query!** If you don't call that for the 2nd query, there won't be any data!

Comment: Also, `yyyy-MM-dd` is the **ISO-8601** format. It's a standard, and the best way to unambiguously indicate date values in code. But for _date-only_ values in an SQL database, with no time component, you might consider using the ISO-8601 _unseparated_ variant: `yyyyMMdd`. This is allowed by the ISO-8601 spec, and solves certain rare compatibility issues in some DBs. Values that include times should still use the separated format you've seen already.

Comment: I called the Execute reader again doesn't change the outcome.  The datepicker shows datetime.  the database has short date.  I can comment out the first block and set the second query nice and clean and it still doesn't return any data. If i couldn't get the correct answer in sqlite studio, i would think the DB had an issue.  i'll try to format the datepicker box that way and see if it works.

Comment: Don't format the date picker box... at least, not where the user sees it. The `Value` property in the box is a `DateTime` object, regardless of the visible format. You only want to care about a ToString() call for the database, and even then this needs to line up with what is actually stored in the table.

Comment: I suggested editing your question to add the updated code, and then also show some sample data in the table and sample value chosen by the user.

Comment: @JoelCoehoom I updated the code.  I still disagree with the cmd. executeREader part.  there are 15 different text boxes that fill from this.  Some work some don't .  it doesn't make any difference if i add the reader to each block or use it for all blcks.  All of the select statements work in Sql.  This project was a larger program running SQLServer and working over a year., i am trying to convert to SQLITE for deployment reasons.  SQLIte has different syntax requirements.  It seems much more picky about date formats since it stores things as strings. even tried add a txtbx over dtpkr

Comment: I agree it's nuts to make 15 separate calls to the database, but that's because you should be able to pull that data back in one query. Right now there are two, and to get query results, you must _execute the query_.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the parameters collection before adding new parameters. Also try changing the name of the reader to be sure you have a new one.

```
'Add avg COMMISION TO stats FORM
cmd.CommandText = "Select Avg(CommissionAmt) cm From SalesData where saledate between @dtfrom24 and @dtto24"
cmd.Parameters.Clear '<<--Add This
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtfrom24", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtstatsfrom.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtto24", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStatsTo.Value
'Put the using statement before you use assign the reader
Using RDR1 As New SQLiteDataReader 'Just try changing the name of the reader
    RDR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
    txtStatsCommAvg.Text = 0
    While RDR1.Read()
             txtStatsCommAvg.Text = RDR1.Item("cm").ToString()
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the errors as per Joel Coehoom, the answer that worked was creating to and from hidden text boxes on the form that linked to the datepicker.  I was then able to format the text box to avoid the datetime format of the picker and match the  string Date format of the database in Sqlite.  here is a sample code block that works fine. All other textboxes on the form fill in now with appropriate values.

```
enter  cmd.CommandText = "Select  A.num, A.Denom, Cast(A.num as Float)/Cast(A.Denom as float) as rnp From(Select(Select CAST(count(Result) as Decimal(5,2))" _
                        & "from LeadData  where (Result = 'Refusal')and CApptDate between @dtfrom49 and @dtto49 as num," _
                        & "(select cast(count(leadid) as decimal(5,2))  from LeadData  where  CApptDate between @dtfrom50 and @dtto50) as Denom)A "
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsfrom49", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStatsFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsto49", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStatsTo.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsfrom50", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStatsFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStatsto50", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStatsTo.Text
                    RDR = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    Using RDR
                        txtStatsRefusalPercent.Text = 0
                        While RDR.Read()
                            txtStatsRefusalPercent.Text = RDR.Item("rnp").ToString()
                        End While

                    End Usingcode here
```